# Left navigation bar item - How to make it NOT truncate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, navigation, uinavigationbar, navigationbar

Ok, I have a fairly simple problem that I do not know how to fix.

In my NavigationBar, I have my left button which is used to go back to the previous view. My app is going through translation, and the actual space for the left button was right for the english name, but now in french it's missing some space. (See the ref)

How can I make it bigger so it doesn't truncate at all?

Thanks.

[image: Reference]

Comment: I'd say reduce the size of the title (the part in the middle), but your screenshot seems to imply a custom layout with an icon, so it's probably in the code that creates this layout...

Comment: And really, what french word starts with "Cla" and end with "ages" that could be used in this place in an app? Claquages?

Comment: Yeah, actually there isn't any "title". Only an icon put on the top of the navigationBar. To answer your question, it's "Clavardages". I'm not the one who choose that word and I cannot change it to somehing shorter... It has to fit lol.

Comment: I hope your french version is targeting Québec, not France. In France, that word does not even exist, it's strictly a Québec thing.

Comment: But back to the original topic, the layout with the icon makes me think you have some code that controls the layout of the navigation bar and thus the site of the back button (or the size of some placeholder in the middle to keep space for the icon).

Comment: I'll look in that direction, thanks. - And yes, it's only targeting Quebec ;)